# Avoiding Large Amounts of Code to Handle Parameters in Oracle Queries

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am making a call to an Oracle database using the Oracle.Data.Client library with a stored procedure that has 3 input arguments and dozens of output arguments.

My code looks like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
using (connection)
{
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "storedProcedureName";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@arg1", arg1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@arg2", arg2);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@arg3", arg3);
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

When I execute this code, Oracle complains about not having enough arguments.  I've ascertained that it wants me to put in some code for each output parameter as well, like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@out1", out1);
cmd.Parameters["@out1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

But this hardly seems elegant, especially if I have to do it with every output argument (and there are many).  Is there a way to handle all of the output arguments at once?  Ideally I would like to keep the stored procedure the same, since it is used in other projects too.

Answer (score 0):

If the procedure has 12 output parameters, you'd need to bind 12 output parameters to your statement.

Now, I'd consider any procedure that had 12 output parameters to be, at a minimum, rather suspect.  That strikes me as way too many parameters for a well-designed API to have to deal with.  The fact that you're trying to put the results into a table implies to me that you really want a procedure that outputs a `sys_refcursor` or some other composite data structure.